# Http status code 412 - Precondition failed

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, http

Getting 412 status code in response while trying to call restful service

While calling a restful service through ajax, I am passing authentication token in request header and a request body which is a json object. The response that I get from server is caught as 412 status code.

> {"code":412,"status":"Precondition Failed","message":"User queryAll failed: Unexpected error parsing authentication token: 7d6f7d04-2b75-480d-8412-e6b9c173fb0e: Unable to convert authentication token to session: Unable to handle credentials from REST request body: [Authentication tag check failed. Message=ct5Rp34R2jgOlMUl29ElZg calculated=jwxpg_IzZKLrQACDM_D8pw]: [Unable to handle credentials from REST request body: [Authentication tag check failed. Message=ct5Rp34R2jgOlMUl29ElZg calculated=jwxpg_IzZKLrQACDM_D8pw]]: [7d6f7d04-2b75-480d-8412-e6b9c173fb0e: Unable to convert authentication token to session: Unable to handle credentials from REST request body: [Authentication tag check failed. Message=ct5Rp34R2jgOlMUl29ElZg calculated=jwxpg_IzZKLrQACDM_D8pw]: [Unable to handle credentials from REST request body: [Authentication tag check failed. Message=ct5Rp34R2jgOlMUl29ElZg calculated=jwxpg_IzZKLrQACDM_D8pw]]]","objectData":null}

Comment: This does indeed sound like a problem. Sounds like the server is unable to convert the authentication token to session. I'm not sure how to help though, considering we don't know anything about the service other than it's restful...

Comment: It looks like there is some sort of encryption algorithm that supposed to be applied in the authentication token. It seems as it is trying to decrypt it but cannot. Do you have any more info on what the service is expecting?